# Array week number

Tags: excel, formula, excel-2003, week-number

I have a spreadsheet we use as our point of sale. It calculate sales by month using this formula Column B is Date of transaction.

Sort by month 1-january-Day is not blank- Cac if D# has X- From column H

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(B5:B9999)=1),--(B5:B9999<>""),--(D5:D9999="x"),H5:H9999)
```

something like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(B5:B9999)=1),--(B5:B9999<>""),--(D5:D9999="x"),H5:H9999)
```

I need this same formula, but I need the Week number (pay by week)
for 52 pay weeks. All I have found is weeknum (1-7)

Thanks in advance

Comment: WEEKNUM() returns the week number. The MS page on that function is a bit confusing though.

Answer (score 0):

You need WEEKNUM rather than WEEKDAY.  For example:

**=WEEKNUM(TODAY()-DATEVALUE("1/1/2013")+1)**  gives you today's week number

Answer (score 0):

From our Barry Houdini's post [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/727593-using-weeknum-in-a-sumproduct-calculation.html): "WEEKNUM is one of those functions that doesn't accept a range argument (like many Analysis ToolPak functions), e.g. this formula `=WEEKNUM(A1:A10)` just returns #VALUE! error"

So I'd suggest a helper column with =WEEKNUM(B5) in Row5 (say ColumnP) and copied down, with your formula adjusted as below (for week #1 result):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((P5:P9999)=1),--(B5:B9999<>""),--(D5:D9999="x"),H5:H9999)
```

This may however give you 53 'weeks' in a year, though I take it rolling "week #53" (less than 7 days) into the next year would be acceptable.